# How to share a common object in each page request of a ASP.net MVC 4 webapp?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I come from "regular" asp.net so i'm a bit (totally) lost with MVC.

What I was doing with my own asp.net programmation pattern :

- I have one custom class objet which represent the "page" and its properties (like mypage.loadJquery, mypage.isLogged, mypage.Title, custom cache logic, etc.)
- This class is instanciate once on top of each ASHX page, I then manipulate a stringbuilder to produce HTML and spit it right at the browser at the end.

  - Having only one request on the ASHX page, i can use my page object instanciated at the top till the end when calling final response.write

Now i'm trying to go for MVC. I "kind of" understood the M/V/C model and the routing concept. I would like to keep my custom "page" object but I lost my page life cycle and I definitely don't know how to instanciate my page object ONCE in at the top of every call.

I need this instanciated ONCE shared object across every models, controllers, views, partial views, htmlhelper...

I realize MVC pattern might be confusing for me at this moment, bu how could I try to reproduce my need ?

(Very concrete exemple : On every request i need to check if the user is logged via his cookies. If it is I round trip the database to get user infos. Then I DO NEED THESE INFOS ON PRATICALLY EVERY model / controller / view of the app, but of course don't want to round back each time to security check and database querying, how can i have these info on the whole mvc cyle ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project I create interface `IViewModel` that contains all fields that I need in my layout/masterpage and set is as model of it so I can easily use them:

IViewModel.cs

```
public interface IViewModel
{
    string Title { get; set; }

    User User { get; set; }
}
```

Layout.cshtml

```
@model IViewModel

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@Model.Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @if (Model.User.IsAuthenticated) {
             You are logged as @Model.User.Name
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

All my models implement that interface (or inherit from ViewModelBase that is default implementation of that class). Additionally I have custom action filter that check if returned ActionResult is (Partial)ViewResult and if Model of it implement my `IViewModel` interface and fill data in that interface.

```
public FillViewModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var viewResult = context.Result as ViewResult;
        if (viewResult != null && viewResult.Model is IViewModel)
        {
            var viewModel = (IViewModel)viewResult.Model;
            // fill data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If i understood well, you can only pass one model to VIEW, so how do you pass your say "customer" model to your view that already implement IViewModel as default model ? Have to put the customer model in a viewbag ? Does it not break the concept ?

Comment: You can create something like ViewModelBase<T> that contains property `Model` or create `CustomerViewModel` that implement `IViewModel`, contains customer data and other additional data eg. for dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

I created many projects like this.  Basically, you can create a base controller class where all the other controllers inherit from it.

```
[Authorize]
public class BaseController : Controller
{

    private Instructor _G_USER = null;

    protected Instructor G_USER 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_G_USER == null)
            {
                _G_USER = Your DB query here
                ViewData["G_USER"] = _G_USER;

            }
            return _G_USER;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your every child class, you can do

```
[Authorize]
public class YourController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if(!G_USER.CAN_DO_THIS)  throw new NoPermissionException();

        return View();
    }
}
```

To use the User in the view, create an extension method.

```
public static class ExtentionMethods
{
    public static USER G_USER(this ViewPage page)
    {            
        return (USER)page.ViewData["G_USER"];
    }
}
```

Then use in the page like this

```
<%=this.G_USER().....%>
```

Comment: Good start but the user data is passed via ViewData and not Model. It might be acceptable i have to test it.

Comment: To be a little more creative, use the extension method